# Android FATAL EXCEPTION Asynch Task #1

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-asynctask

I am trying to make a simple weather app. Everytime I try and access the Yahoo weather api to return a JSON object, I get this exception. To do the task without the api, I copy pasted the JSON object into a separate string and have been working with that string as the JSON object.

This is my asynch task:

public class WeatherInfoThread extends AsyncTask{

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String resultString = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22"+location+"%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            connection = url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        try {
            jsonInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        resultString = jsonInfo;



        try {
            weatherinfo = new JSONObject(testString);
            // Log.d(JSON_INFO,weatherinfo.toString()+"df");
            JSONObject channel = weatherinfo.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("channel");
            JSONObject item = channel.getJSONObject("item");
            currentTemp = item.getJSONObject("condition");
            cCurrentInt = currentTemp.getInt("code");

            forecast = item.getJSONArray("forecast");
            cOne = forecast.getJSONObject(1).getString("text");
            cTwo = forecast.getJSONObject(2).getString("text");
            cThree = forecast.getJSONObject(3).getString("text");
            cFour = forecast.getJSONObject(4).getString("text");
            cFive = forecast.getJSONObject(5).getString("text");
            dOne = forecast.getJSONObject(1).getString("day");
            dTwo = forecast.getJSONObject(2).getString("day");
            dThree = forecast.getJSONObject(3).getString("day");
            dFour = forecast.getJSONObject(4).getString("day");
            dFive = forecast.getJSONObject(5).getString("day");


            // Log.d(JSON_INFO,forecast.get(1).toString()+"ddf");




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the error I got:

12-16 16:48:06.677 10523-10549/com.example.aakashmahesh.weatherapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
                                                                                         at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
                                                                                         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
                                                                                         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:70)
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
                                                                                         at com.example.aakashmahesh.weatherapp.MainActivity$WeatherInfoThread.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:269)
                                                                                         at com.example.aakashmahesh.weatherapp.MainActivity$WeatherInfoThread.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:250)
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
                                                                                      Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
                                                                                         at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
                                                                                         at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
                                                                                         at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
                                                                                         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236) 
                                                                                         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:70) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271) 
                                                                                         at com.example.aakashmahesh.weatherapp.MainActivity$WeatherInfoThread.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:269) 
                                                                                         at com.example.aakashmahesh.weatherapp.MainActivity$WeatherInfoThread.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:250) 
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305) 
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
                                                                                      Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
                                                                                         at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55) 
                                                                                         at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405) 
                                                                                         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236) 
                                                                                         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:70) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168) 
                                                                                         at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271) 
                                                                                         at com.example.aakashmahesh.weatherapp.MainActivity$WeatherInfoThread.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:269) 
                                                                                         at com.example.aakashmahesh.weatherapp.MainActivity$WeatherInfoThread.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:250) 
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305) 
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
12-16 16:48:06.677 1370-17136/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.aakashmahesh.weatherapp/.MainActivity
12-16 16:48:06.737 1370-17136/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 647K, 12% free 16559K/18695K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
12-16 16:48:06.767 10523-10523/com.example.aakashmahesh.weatherapp D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
12-16 16:48:06.767 10523-10523/com.example.aakashmahesh.weatherapp D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
12-16 16:48:06.767 10523-10523/com.example.aakashmahesh.weatherapp D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so

```
                                                                         [ 12-16 16:48:06.767 10523:10523 D/         ]
                                                                         HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8071030, tid 10523
```

Comment: Sure there is more log. The exception you are posting is missing the line where the exception is happening. Please, post the full related log

Comment: yes, the stacktrace should tell you the line# it is occurring at.

Answer (score 1):

read the error, will you?

**Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?) at**

Answer (score 1):

May be you did not write the permission to access Internet in Manifest file

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

Comment: Thank you. I did not write the permission to access the Internet in Manifest file. I was stumped. Will not forget this answer. Thank you.